# Call a function on DOM ready from outside <head>?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jQuery you can wrap all your code in `$(function() { ... });` and have it fire when the DOM is ready, but what if you want to put that in the middle of the page somewhere? Isn't it possible that the DOM ready event will fire before it processes that chunk of code and it'll get missed? Is there a way to guarantee it'll get fired?

Comment: Doesn't "ready" imply that the whole document has been parsed? (Just intuition, I'm not a web dev.)

Comment: @delnan: You'd think so, but who knows. I think it's supposed to fire when the DOM tree is ready. JavaScript isn't part of the DOM tree...so... I don't know. Just wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can place a `<script>..</script>` block anywhere in your code:

- if you use `.ready()` (or [equivalent syntax](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)) to execute code when the dom is loaded, it will be executed when the whole page is loaded, no matter where you placed the `ready()` handler.
- if you simply put code within the `<script>` tags, then it will be executed whenever the parser reaches that point of the code.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not possible for the DOM ready event to fire when the DOM is not ready. It will be fired, regardless of where you place your script.

Answer (score 1):

DOM ready doesn't fire until the whole DOM tree has been loaded, so it will work.

Also, if you happen to do `$(function() { ... })` after DOM ready has already fired, jQuery is smart and will just execute your callback right away.

Answer (score 1):

No, the DOM ready event should not get fired until the DOM is ready, meaning until it processes the last closing tag and constructs the DOM fully.

You should be fine placing your `<script>` tags with the jQuery ready anywhere in the page.

Answer (score 1):

DOM ready event will fire before it processes that chunk of code 
only if connection to web-server will fails before the browser download the whole html page.
In such a strange case dom ready event will fires, but your inline scripts fails.